# Proving braking distance formula $ x = \frac{v_0^2}{2 \, \mu \, g} $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, friction, education

I'm tried to prove the braking distance formula:

$$ x = \frac{v_0^2}{2 \, \mu \, g} $$

with $ v_0 $ initial speed, $ \mu $ static friction coefficient, $ g $ gravitational acceleration on the earth. I used the first Newton's principle to get $ a = \mu \, g $; then, assuming a uniformly accelerated motion and $ 
x(t=0)=0 $, i got:

$$ x = v_0 \, t + \frac{a \, t^2}{2} $$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Final velocity is zero.

Comment: Hello @BillN thank you a lot for your suggestion; i got the result i was looking for by applying the work energy theorem